# What should I know about the F# CTP?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, f#

I want to start playing with f#. What is the CTP of F# about?

Is it something I can use to install in vs2008? What about express?

Answer (score 7):

CTP = Community Technology Preview

The CTP should install ok into VS2008. I've installed it into the Visual Studio Shell with no problems (it works fine so long as the shell is installed *prior* to the CTP)

See [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/05/02/f-in-20-minutes-part-i.aspx) for more info re. the CTP and the VS installation.

Answer (score 3):

CTP = Community Technology Preview. You can download the F# msi and install it with your current VS2008.

I'm not sure if it works with Express, but there's also a free visual studio shell as well.

Comment: Here's a Wikipedia entry on MSFT's software release cycle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Answer (score 3):

See also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734525/getting-started-with-f

which talks about 'tools needed' as well as tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't work with Express, but you can use [Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933751.aspx).