# Will F# ever be a mainstream language like C# is? Or will it remain a niche language?

Tags: f#

Will F# ever be a mainstream language like C# is? Or will it remain a niche language?
Do you foresee any clients coming to you with projects executed in F#?
Will a professional programmer be able to make a living from F#. What sort of demand do you predict for F# programmers?

Kind regards,

Comment: This should be a community wiki.

Comment: I don't really see how anyone could make an informed, objective statement answering this question, so I vote to close as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: I am just looking for an opinion before I make an investment in F#. With so many new things coming out of the MS shop lately, its always better to get a second opinion.

Comment: My informed and objective statement: as a professional programmer earning a living from F# with clients coming to me with their F# projects I can tell you that I think the answer to those two of your questions is "yes".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are people making a living out of functional programming today. For examples, see the [commercial users of functional programming workshop](http://cufp.galois.com/) which is being held each year.

For the first version of F#, Microsoft is targetting engineering, mathematical, financial and data-processing applications (if I remember correctly). Whether that is a niche or not depends on your perspective :) but it seems like a reasonable market.

Thanks to F#'s excellent .NET integration you can, to a large extent, choose to make your projects using F#. What should your client care. If you get a competitive advantage from that with respect to C# programmers, maybe you'd better hope F# *does not* hit the mainstream...

Lastly, certainly F# (and Scala) are indicators that at least functional programming will become "more mainstream". But when is a language considered mainstream? I wouldn't be surprised if there are many many more lines of code in C and COBOL out there than C#,VB and Java combined. So from a C programmer's perspective, C# is a niche language. I think programming languages, thanks to virtual machines, are becoming more diversified in general (think also Ruby, Python and Haskell, for example, not taking into account all the smaller languages like Clojure, Ioke,...).

Comment: +1 for you,  "When is a language concidered mainstream?": a mainstream language is one that has the most blogs and naive tutorials.  We will be mainstream when I can give you a 5-minute demo on how to build an enterprise web application that will not survive in the marketplace or even qualify as a business, yet look fruitful enough that you will use it to save time and money.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer this for sure. Certainly it's highly subjective. We can just wait and see what happens. But one thing is for sure. Even if F# remains a minority language, ideas and functional style of programming will be further added to other languages gradually. You can't say C# 3.0 is the same as C# 1.0. It's just a matter of name similarity.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that F# will ever reach the popularity of C# or other imperative languages because most applications are designed imperatively and most programmers think in this way.

But F# provides many very interesting features like LOP, compiler compilers, computation expressions (async workflows), quotations, units of measure.

Many problems can be formulated much better and more concise in a functional programming language (look at those F# examples using async {} or seq {}) and because F# is a bit more mainstream than e.g. Haskell (it has got the .NET framework that simplifies many tasks and is not purely functional!), it will be easier for many programmers to get into functional programming and learn it's advantages.

In addition, it's harder to write wrong code in F# than e.g. in C because you have good type checking, many strong types infered by the compiler and immutable values - You can intuitively prove the correctness of a functional algorithm which is often hard in an imperative one. Just think of this code which should count the number of zeros in an array:

```
int countZeros;
for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
  if (data[i] = 0) {
   countZeros++;
 }
}
```

This all are factors that will bring people to use F#. The rest is marketing (Microsoft should have a F# Express Edition in VS2010!!)

Comment: It works with the (free) VS Shell, so that's pretty close to an express edition.

Comment: Yeah, but don't you have to install an expensive regular VS Edition first to use the Shell?

Comment: No, the shell is a free download.  You can use F# today for free; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773642/f-ctp-question

Answer (score 1):

I can't see functional languages as a whole becoming mainstream.  Ultimately anything that is alien to a mere mortal human way of thinking is never going to be mainstream.

Functional programming will however be more than niche.  Its benefits in terms of expressing a problem that can be solved over multiple processors is compelling.  What I see is F# libraries for specific purposes and/or F# concepts migrating to C#.

Comment: How functional programming is mortal to human thinking? Isn't is just we were used to? I mean if start with someone who has no idea what programming is, will he or she learn recursion and functional way of solving problems or mutations and state change?

Comment: I think it depends, for a person with no programming experience, functional paradigm might be more compelling. For one with low-level programming language like C or assembly, functional paradigm might be too much to take.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Most people know how to make a cup of tea.  Can that be done functionally, doing somethings in parallel?  Perhaps, but its more natural to think of the procedure as a sequence.  This is what I mean by human, life is full of sequences not of functions.  Those with a grounding in mathematics may warm to the functional approach but they do not represent the majority.  Without a mathematical approach to problems functional programming is hard, period.  There is enough of skill shortage as it is, whether functional is superior or not it'll be no good if you can't get the staff.

Comment: Ah, the poor (and mythical) "average programmer". 40 years ago he could not program without goto; then with object-orientation; then with generics; now with functional programming? This thinking, frankly, is elitist, insulting, and most importantly, wrong.

Comment: @kurt: Its not quite clear to me why you are insulted? In what way are my comments elitist?  Why do you think the "average programmer" is a myth?  Do you believe that all have equal ability?  Its functional programming itself which is elitist.  Want proof?  Look up answers to the question "What is a monad?"  Honestly how many developers do you know that would grasp this, I know that I don't.  Unless functional programming can be made more accessible it'll never be mainstream.  The vast majority of tasks are easier to reason out imperatively.

Comment: My 2c - I would have thought that functional thinking is more, not less natural for most people.  I find that for me, designing a program in a C-like language imperatively to solve a non-trivial problem is often a double challenge; tricky to figure out the solution, and then tricky to figure out a good way to write it correctly.  Designing a functional program is usually tricky to figure out the solution, but then simple to write.

Comment: The phrase "alien to a mere mortal human way of thinking" seems to equate functional programmers with gods. If I don't understand something about F#, should I look up to some functional programming god and ask for enlightenment?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as Kurt to say that the attitude is "insulting", but it definitely sounds like you're saying that your own personal experience must be true for everyone. And for what its worth, a "monad" is a scary sounding worth for something that's otherwise ridiculously simple (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Computation_Expressions for an explanation) -- the only thing that makes them hard is knowing where they should and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Furthermore, there is nothing "naturally" imperative (or functionial!) about human thinking. Do you think about the cup of tea as storage in a von neumann machine, in which you "pour" a value of tea? Learning a craft, any craft, is about how to apply the right way of thinking and problem solving to get to a good solution efficiently. Does a structural engineer care whether the finite element method is natural? I apologize that I came over as harsh, it's just that these (imo) misonceptions push my buttons :)

Comment: @Princess:  Its clear from the subjective tag that comments here can only be opinion.  Since the comments I made have my name attached to them it is my opinion being expressed; there is no suggestion that my opinion "must be true" it is just my opinion.  I've read that explanation you linked before, you are clearly way cleverer than I because I find the explanation far from "ridiculously simple".

Comment: @kurt: "alien to a mere mortal human way of thinking" does perhaps come over stronger than intended if you take it too seriously.  I certainly don't think functional programmers are gods but I do consider them to be considerably brighter than me.  Yet having worked with many other developers over a number of decades I believe that I'm at least an "average" developer.

Comment: Just for completeness, the intro to the linked page does say "Computation expressions are easily the **most difficult**, yet most powerful language constructs to understand in F#."

Comment: A few things I've seen indicate that it's easier to teach Scheme as a first programming language than after the student has experience with procedural languages.  I suspect that the issue is the difficulty in learning two different paradigms, not that one is inherently more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the expert but I think one of the advantages of functional programming is the relatively painless approach to parallelism and multicore processing. Therefore in a view of the recent Microsoft announcement in this area, namely Axum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd795202.aspx which is an another approach to parallel programming, I really doubt that F# will ever go mainstream. If Axum is adopted, it will be probably integrated with C# (like Code Contracts moved from Lab to C# 4.0) and F# will be used only in very specific domains.

Comment: Axum does look promising.  It reminds me of embedded development using a Message Oriented Realtime Executive (M.O.R.E.) way back in the late 80s early 90s.  It just goes to show "there is nothing new under the sun".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it happening until ***Functional Programming*** going mainstream.

Comment: How can an answer that starts with an "I" be a CW :P oh well

Comment: first it is cw because there are more learned and knowledgeable persons out there. secondly i cannot claim that i'm telling a universal rule/truth or on behalf of others that this thing is going to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about F# is the powerful combination of programming paradigms it allows. You can write most of your program in the functional style - brief, elegant and free from side effects (common bugs). But when you encounter a problem you can't solve functionally, you can then enter a short section of imperative code to get past it. It's also very easy to mark sections of your code as asynchronous, and it will then run in parallell if you have multiple cores/processors. The solution will be much easier than a C# equivalent. After witnessing a demo by one of the creators of F#, I was left with the impression that they have managed to extract great features from both Python and Erlang. F# will probably be fronted as the .NET answer to these two classes of languages and could eventually achieve a comparable degree of mainstream adoption.

Answer (score 0):

OTOH, if you take up F#, that's one more mainstream programmer on-board....

Avoiding it is a self-fulfilling prophecy.

Answer (score -3):

In line-of-business development, it will never happen. It is simply too hard, so the average LOB developer will never be able to maintain it. In higher-end software companies, it could happen though.

Comment: I know some C programmers who think C# is too hard, and have heard similar arguments against the use of classes and interfaces from them. The LOB argument is bogus.

Comment: "I know some..." sounds like a proof-by-example fallacy to me. I'm willing to bet I'm right, we'll see in 10 years.

Comment: Of course it's not a proof. We're in a crystal ball discussion, not a mathematical argument. I just get annoyed at the "average developer" myth: if there exists such a creature, he/she does not have any say in the matter anyway - I assume these average programmers are directed by average managers? So they'll use what the manager read on the trade magazine yesterday.